# Combining 3 elasticsearch queries into one

Tags: elasticsearch

My basic problem is that i have three separate queries performing spatial,temporal and keyword search. i want to combine them into one query in a way as the following use case describes :

**user enters a keyword for searching the document. the query returns certain documents. user then narrows down his search by spatial searching for which there is a spatial query and then further narrows down the results through temporal searching.**

**Keyword query**

```
"query": {
    "match" : { "metadata.o2r.title" : "geosciences" } 
  }
```

**Spatial query**

```
   {
                            "query": {
                                    "bool": {
                                            "must": {
                                                    "match_all": {}
                                            },
                                            "filter": {
                                                    "geo_shape": {
                                                            "metadata.o2r.spatial.geometry": {
                                                                    "shape": {
                                                                            "type": "polygon",
                                                                            "coordinates":
                                                                                coords


                                                                    },
                                                                    "relation": "within"
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
```

**temporal query**

```
{
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                                "range": {
                                    "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin": {
                                        "from": lower
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "metadata.o2r.temporal.end": {
                                        "to": upper
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
```

**The basic idea is to provide documents with certain keywords for a given location for certain period of time through a single query**

**Combined Query**

```
"query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [  {
                            "match" : { "metadata.o2r.title" : "geosciences"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                        "filter": {
                            "geo_shape": {
                                "metadata.o2r.spatial.geometry": {
                                    "shape": {
                                        "type": "polygon",
                                        "coordinates": coords


                                    },
                                    "relation": "within"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                      },
                          {
                                "range": {
                                    "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin": {
                                        "from": lower
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "metadata.o2r.temporal.end": {
                                        "to": upper
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                        ]
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Put them all in a `bool/must` and there ya go :-)

Comment: @Val putting them all together will restrict the user to enter all the three requirements at once. while i want him just to enter the keyword at start and then later he can narrow down those results (having that keyword) based on either temporal or spatial query. maybe some kind of OR operator.?

Comment: It sounds like you need to construct the query bit by bit... so use a `bool/must` as advised and include the new constraint in it as soon as the user specifies it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used a bool/match operator to combine all queries

```
{
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                                "range": {
                                    "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin": {
                                        "from": from
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "metadata.o2r.temporal.end": {
                                        "to": to
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": {
                                        "match_all": {}
                                    },
                                    "filter": {
                                        "geo_shape": {
                                            "metadata.o2r.spatial.geometry": {
                                                "shape": {
                                                    "type": "polygon",
                                                    "coordinates": coords


                                                },
                                                "relation": "within"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
    "match" : { "metadata.o2r.title" : "geosciences" }
  }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
```